# How to implement stack which stores only unique values in Java

Tags: java, stack, hashset, linkedhashset

I'm trying to implement the unique stack. If I try to extend the stack class and use the contains it will look the entire stack and the time complexity will become O(n). So I tried to extend the LinkedHashSet which will remove duplicates by itself and maintains the order. I'm able to implement all the methods except the pop.

Can anyone share thoughts here?

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.Stack;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class UniqueStack<E> extends LinkedHashSet<E>{

    private int size = 0;

    @Override
    public Stream<E> stream() {
        return super.stream();
    }

    public boolean push(E e) {
        if (!contains(e)) {
            ++size;
            return super.add(e);
        }
        return false;
    }

    public E pop() {       
       // struck here
    return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use both a `Stack` and `HashSet` as a part of `UniqueStack`? Also, `Stack` should be replaced with `ArrayDeque`.

Comment: @JacobG. If I use stack and HashSet. I have to store the same data in both stack and hashset. I will end up, maintaining the same data. it will consume more memory

Comment: Is memory *really* an issue here? How many elements would you be storing at most?

Comment: I need to crawl a site. Which has millions of urls. I will be using the DFS. So I need stack.

Comment: The amount of memory required is identical whether or not you use a Stack/HashSet combo or LinkedHashSet, so long as you're storing objects. If you want O(1) performance, you need a set, and if you want a stack, you need a stack or a linked list. The LinkedHashSet combines the two by storing references to itself via as part of a hashset and a linked list.

Comment: @Compass yeah, you're correct. Actually using a HashSet and Stack/ArrrayDequeAsStack will save memory by removing duplicates. While crawling we may get more number of duplicates and adding them to the stack will consume more memory whereas maintaining a hashset can actually prevent adding the duplicates and saves a lot of memory. In turn also reduces the number of calls we make to the DB to check if the url is already processed.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash
Actually the comment added by Compass@ resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it would be best to use an `instance` of a regular stack for stack operations but use the efficiency of a `HashSet` to track duplicates.  Additional methods could be added using the same idea.

```
    UniqueStack<Integer> stack = new UniqueStack<>();

    stack.push(10);
    stack.push(20);
    stack.push(30);
    stack.push(40);
    stack.push(30); // ignored
    stack.push(50);

    System.out.println(stack);
    int v = stack.pop();
    System.out.println(v);
    System.out.println(stack);
    stack.push(1);
    stack.push(2);
    System.out.println(stack);
    v = stack.pop();
    System.out.println(v);
    System.out.println(stack);
```

The output of this is

> [10, 20, 30, 40, 50] 
>   50 
>   [10, 20, 30, 40] 
>   [10, 20, 30, 40, 1, 2] 
>   2 
>   [10, 20, 30, 40, 1]

```
class UniqueStack<E> extends LinkedHashSet<E> {

    Stack<E> stack = new Stack<>();
    private int size = 0;


    public Stream<E> stream() {
        return stack.stream();
    }

    public boolean push(E e) {
        if (!contains(e)) {
            ++size;
            stack.push(e);
            return add(e);
        }
        return false;
    }

    public E pop() {
        E val = null;
        if (!stack.isEmpty()) {
            --size;
            val = stack.pop();
            remove(val);
        }
        return val;
    }
}
```